# Python Bokeh legend cut off. How can legend height exceed plot height?

Tags: python, legend, bokeh

I created a plot with a legend similar to the example in the documentation..

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

output_file("legend_labels.html")

p = figure(toolbar_location="above")

r0 = p.circle(x, y)
r1 = p.line(x, y)

r2 = p.line(x, 2*y, line_dash=[4, 4], line_color="orange", line_width=2)

r3 = p.square(x, 3*y, fill_color=None, line_color="green")
r4 = p.line(x, 3*y, line_color="green")

legend = Legend(legends=[
    ("sin(x)",   [r0, r1]),
    ("2*sin(x)", [r2]),
    ("3*sin(x)", [r3, r4])
], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

show(p)
```

but in my case the legend is higher than the plot and is therefore cut off. How can I let the legend height exceed the plot height?

Comment: I get correct looking output on a recent dev build. What version are you using? It is always critical to always include version information in any request for help.

Comment: Sorry, I use python 2.7.12 and bokeh 0.12.1. And yes, this example works fine, I just meant it is similar to mine. I have many datasets in my code though, and therefore the legends gets very long and then it is cut off wenn it exceeds the plot height. If you add a very small height to the example figure the legend will be cut off too.